# Chain of failures, betrayals and ingratitudes "against" or "towards"?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-meaning

I am proofreading a translation and although the literal translation of the original says ***towards***, I am tempted to put "against" instead because of the three nouns enumerated. The sentence is:

> Her life was a chain of failures, betrayals and ingratitudes ***towards/against*** her benefactor, yet he never recoiled and went on consoling her and investing in her.

Would ***against*** be correct here? Is it appropriate for ***failures, betrayals and ingratitudes***?

Comment: Neither really work, which you can already see from *these are my failures against you* and *these are my failures towards you*. I would prefer finding a way to use verbs: *All her life, she had failed, betrayed, x-ed her benefactor, yet...* ---need to find a good x, of course!

Comment: Good thought! I will try... Pity I lose _chain of failures_ though. I liked the expression :)

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't possible. There's no standard "prepositional" term for the context ***a chain of failures** [preposition defining relationship between preceding and following nouns] **her benefactor***. The normal preposition for the second element would be (where in any case it's not clear to me whether ***a chain of*** is supposed to extend to ***betrayals*** or not) would be *a chain of] **betrayals** OF **her benefactor***, and for the final one it's *[a chain of] **ingratitudes** TO / TOWARD / TOWARDS **her benefactor***. There are no "repeated" elements to be "deleted".

Comment: ...maybe *Her life was a chain of failures and betrayals, **and of** ingratitude towards her benefactor* (I don't think much of plural "ingratitudes" here).

Comment: @FF: Very precious points!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer my own question, with the help of all the precious clues I received in the comments. I would turn the words around and say:

> All her life she betrayed her benefactor and showed no gratitude to him. All her life was a chain of failures, and yet he never recoiled, but went on consoling her and investing in her.

It doesn't look too bad, and it seems to preserve all the meaning of the previous variant. I am open to any improvements.